# Realm order of insert or update

Tags: android, realm

I am using **Realm** in order to persist objects for an **Android** project.
The problem is that I have a composition of many classes and inner fields as classes and lists of them.
Something like

```
class A extends RealmObject{
   @PrimaryKey long id;
   B b;
} 

class B extends RealmObject{
   @PrimaryKey long id;
   RealmList<C> cList;
}

class C extends RealmObject{
  @PrimaryKey long id;
  Date date;
  String value;
  //other fields....
}
```

The problem is that I want to update some of the fields of **C** or insert new **C** in the **RealmList of B**. In **what order** should I do that in order to preserve the relations? Can anyone give a real example? Also, Realm doesn't support auto incrementation for IDs and currently I am setting them to currentTimeInMillis when initiated. Is there a better alternative to that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let your model classes be

```
class A extends RealmObject{
   @PrimaryKey
   private long id;
   private B b;

   public A(){
       //required empty constructor
   }

   public A(long id){
       this.id = id;
   }

   public B getB(){
       return b;
   }

   public void setB(B b){
       this.b = b;
   }
} 

class B extends RealmObject{
   @PrimaryKey
   private long id;
   private RealmList<C> cList = new RealmList<>();

   public B(){
       //required empty constructor
   }

   public B(long id){
   this.id = id;
   }

   public RealmList<C> getCList(){
       return cList;
   }

   public void setCList(RealmList<C> cList){
       this.cList = cList;
   }
}

class C extends RealmObject{
  @PrimaryKey 
  private long id;
  private Date date;
  private String value;
  //other fields....

  public C(){
      //required empty constructor
  }

  public C(long id){
      this.id = id;
  }
}
```

**Example - 1: Creating new objects and assigning it according to hierarchy**

```
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();

    C c = new C(id);
    realm.insertOrUpdate(c);

    B b = new B(id);
    RealmList<C> list = b.getcList();
    list.add(c);
    realm.insertOrUpdate(b);

    A a = new A(id);
    a.setB(b);
    realm.insertOrUpdate(a);
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

**Example - 2: Updating existing entry in the DB**

```
    C c = realm.where(C.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    c.setValue("New Value"); //setter method for value
    c.insertOrUpdate();
    //while updating the existing entry in the database, you need not worry about the hierarchy, Realm will maintain the same hierarchy for updates
    //If you want to copy the existing entry from one object to another, you can use combination of method-1 and method-2
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(a);` can be replaced with an insert, much faster

Comment: Thanks @TimCastelijns did not know about this, just read the docs and looks much more efficient. Updated the answer.

Comment: Me neither, EpicPandaForce told me a while ago :)

Comment: wrapper classes? What wrapper classes?

Comment: my mistake, no wrapper classes

Comment: What if I want to only update the objects. Or in the case when I am retrieving A and B from realm, but then creating a new object for C and inserting it into the list of B which is non-existent and also have to instantiate this list?

Comment: As I told @toshkinl this is just an example of how you are supposed to do it. Instead of creating new object, if you want to just update it, then just query it, update it and just update the realm. No additional operations required in that case

Comment: I will update the part -2 of the answer in a while to solve this issue too

Comment: Update it to setIds as primaryKeys so people looking at the answer will have all they need.

Comment: Updated the answer @toshkinl

Answer (score 4):

It would be something like this:

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        // using managed objects
        A a = realm.where(A.class).findFirst(aId);
        if(a == null) {
           a = realm.createObject(A.class, aId);
        }
        B b = realm.where(B.class).findFirst(bId);
        if(b == null) {
           b = realm.createObject(B.class, bId);
        }
        a.setB(b);

        // in case of managed objects
        for(List<Long> cId : cIds) {
            C c = realm.where(C.class).findFirst(cId);
            if(c == null) {
                c = realm.createObject(C.class, cId);
            }
            if(!b.getCs().contains(c)) { 
                b.getCs().add(c);
            }
        }

        // in case of unmanaged objects of C, adding to managed object B
        b.getCs().addAll(realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(unmanagedCs));

      ////// adding new unmanaged objects to Realm
        A _a = new A();
        _a.setId(aId);
        realm.insertOrUpdate(_a);

        B _b = new B();
        _b.setId(bId);
        _b.setCs(new RealmList<C>());
        for(C _c : unmanagedCs) {
           _b.add(_c);
        }
        realm.insertOrUpdate(_b);
    }
});
```

Comment: Both answers are good. The other one is just shorter and was first and therefore I accepted it. But upvoted yours!